# Rewrite query so the WHEN clause won't affect Right outer Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, I just want to change the inner join to right outer join but it keeps inner joining everything. I've tried all kinds of join but the results for inner join keeps on showing

Or if anyone has any tips on how I can rewrite this query, joining 2 tables with their own `WHERE` clause filter without the `WHERE` clause messing up the `JOIN`. And I read somewhere that the `WHERE` clause affects the `JOIN`

```
DECLARE @BranchC VARCHAR(500) = '01001'
DECLARE @Range1 VARCHAR(255) = '202101'
DECLARE @Range2 VARCHAR(255) = '202201'

SELECT
    sub1.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ISNULL(r1.ItemID, r2.ItemID) AS ItemID,
            r2.TotalItemPrice as R2_ItemPrice,
            r1.TotalItemPrice AS R1_ItemPrice
        FROM
            (
                SELECT 
                    ItemID,
                    SUM(TotalItemPrice) AS TotalItemPrice
                FROM
                    DM.M
                WHERE
                    0 = 0
                    AND InvoiceYearMonth IN (SELECT VALUE FROM dbo.SplitString(@Range1,','))
                    AND BranchCode IN (SELECT ITEM FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@BranchC,N','))
                GROUP BY
                    ItemID
            ) r1
            INNER JOIN -- wanted to make this as right outer join
            (
                SELECT 
                    ItemID,
                    SUM(TotalItemPrice) AS TotalItemPrice
                FROM
                    DM.M
                WHERE
                    0 = 0
                    AND InvoiceYearMonth IN (SELECT VALUE FROM dbo.SplitString(@Range2,','))
                    AND BranchCode IN (SELECT ITEM FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@BranchC,N','))
                GROUP BY
                    ItemID
            ) r2
            ON r1.ItemID = r2.ItemID
        WHERE
            0 = 0
            AND r1.ItemID NOT IN (SELECT ItemID FROM DM.C)
            AND r2.ItemID NOT IN (SELECT ItemID FROM DM.C)
    ) sub1
```

Left Outer join (Top 2)

| ItemID | r2_ItemPrice | r1_ItemPrice |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 207106 | 8555.65 | 13717.01 |
| 972304 | 11165 | 11879.26 |

Right Outer join (Top 2)

| ItemID | r2_ItemPrice | r1_ItemPrice |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 207106 | 8555.65 | 13717.01 |
| 972304 | 11165 | 11879.26 |

LEFT join (Top 2)

| ItemID | r2_ItemPrice | r1_ItemPrice |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 207106 | 8555.65 | 13717.01 |
| 972304 | 11165 | 11879.26 |

RIGHT join (Top 2)

| ItemID | r2_ItemPrice | r1_ItemPrice |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 207106 | 8555.65 | 13717.01 |
| 972304 | 11165 | 11879.26 |

FULL outer join (Top 2)

| ItemID | r2_ItemPrice | r1_ItemPrice |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 207106 | 8555.65 | 13717.01 |
| 972304 | 11165 | 11879.26 |

I've tried to remove all where clause and use AND clause as a filter to no avail. Both right outer join and inner join is showing.

Comment: First of all - the first condition in any of the `WHERE` clauses **CANNOT** have a leading `AND`.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results so we can understand what you are attempting to accomplish.

Comment: 1. I accidentally deleted 0=0. So 0=0 and r1 etc etc.

2. ....Uhm.. Im not sure how I can provide more because the query is HUUUUUUUGE. hmm..

Comment: Thats the minimal of [mre] you don't show us your actual code, you build the simplest query you can which demonstrates the issue you are having. As it stands we have no way of telling whether its your join conditions or your where clause that is causing your issues, because we don't actually know what your issues are.

Comment: Ok I edited the code, hope it sufficient.

Comment: Why do you want right outer join? Most people find `main table left join optional data` much easier to understand than `optional data right join main table`.

Comment: Well, both the data is from the same table. The thing that differentiates the 2 data is the filter. So what Im comparing, is a Branch with 2022 data and the same branch with 2021 data.
So 2021 data right outer join 2022 data.
Tho using the query that we have here, it doesnt matter what Join I use. The results are the same.
The Query is from the company and they just threw me the code and said "you can do it "

Comment: All the data you show us is identical - we have no idea what data you are starting with, nor what results you are looking for - if you don't know what you want how do you think we can help?

Comment: Well, the data results are the same when using different kinds of joins. It keeps on doing inner join.
I just want the Right Outer Join to work for the query (between r1 and r2)
There's more than 10M rows here so i'm not sure how I can provide data.